# Why I can't create an RTMP session on VideoCore?

Tags: ios, rtmp, videocore

I am getting the following log while connecting on Adobe FMS server.

I wonder "/publicorigin/" of my url has disappeared in the log.

```
2016-04-16 05:37:49.661 SampleBroadcaster-Swift[2016:531501] Creating context
2016-04-16 05:37:52.037 SampleBroadcaster-Swift[2016:531569] rtmp://sample.com:1935/publicorigin/160416_05_0?14991850%3Alv259769050%3A68%3A1460752176%3A0%3A1460752469%3A91d440bb3a1ef858
2016-04-16 05:37:52.037 SampleBroadcaster-Swift[2016:531569] lv259769050
Connecting:sample.com:1935, stream name:160416_05_0?14991850%3Alv259769050%3A68%3A1460752176%3A0%3A1460752469%3A91d440bb3a1ef858/lv259769050
ClientState: 1
ClientState: 2
ClientState: 3
Want read:4096, read:1410
ClientState: 4
Not enough s1 size
Want read:2686, read:1410
ClientState: 5
Not enough s2 size
Want read:1276, read:253
ClientState: 6
Tracking command(1, connect)
Want read:4096, read:200
Steam in buffer size:200
First byte:0x2, header type:0
Handle message:5
Received server window size: 2500000
Steam in buffer size:184
First byte:0x2, header type:0
Handle message:6
Received peer bandwidth limit: 49152 type: 2
Steam in buffer size:167
First byte:0x3, header type:0
Handle message:20
Received invoke
Received invoke _error
Steam in buffer size:30
First byte:0x3, header type:0
Handle message:20
Received invoke
Received invoke close
Want read:4096, read:30
Steam in buffer size:30
First byte:0x3, header type:0
Handle message:20
Received invoke
Received invoke close
```

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).